# Internal representation of Haskell lists?

Tags: list, haskell, data-structures

Haskell supports some basic operations for recursing through lists, like `head`, `tail`, `init` and `last`. I'm wondering, internally, how Haskell is representing its list data? If it's a singly-linked list, then `init` and `last` operations could become costly as the list grows. If it's a doubly-linked list, all four operations could be made **`O(1)`** quite easily, albeit at the expense of some memory. Either way, it's important for me to know, so I can write appropriate code. (although, the ethos of functional programming seems to be one of "ask what it does, not how it does it").

Comment: "ask what it does, not how it does it" Not if you're concerned about writing code that is reasonably fast ;)

Comment: Well, that's what I think :-) Hence my question.

Comment: "If it's a doubly-linked list, all four operations could be made O(1) quite easily" actually, it's not that easy if you want to stay purely functional, so ordinary doubly-linked lists aren't used much in Haskell. Doing all off those in _O_ (1) while remaining purely functional requires rather more sophisticated data structures – however it turns out that, by exploiting Haskell's lazyness, you can get much further with _O_ (1) operations (or in some way amortised _O_ (_n_), which is almost as good) on its singly-linked linked lists than would be possible in any procedural language.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Lists are represented as ... singly linked lists. The definition is given by:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

which you could write as:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

The memory layout is entirely defined by this.

- Constructors are heap allocated
- Internal polymorphic fields are pointers to other allocated nodes
- The spine is lazy

So you end up with something like this:

[image]

So `head` is *O(1)* on this structure, while `last` or `(++)` is *O(n)*

There is no magic to data structures in Haskell - their straight-forward definition makes entirely clear what the complexity will be (modulo laziness). If you need different complexity, use a different structure (such as IntMap, Sequence, HashMap, Vector etc)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure it's necessary to emphasize how clear/obvious this answer should be - I'm a beginner to Haskell, and coming from C it's a huge change, so I'm still figuring stuff out. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I don't mean its "easy", just that there's no magic involved. If you simply look at the data type definition, it is all derivable.

Comment: Two big caveats: **laziness** and **fusion**. Laziness means that, for example, in `xs ++ ys` you only pay the cost of the append to the extent that you traverse the result list; `head (xs ++ ys)` is O(1), not O(n). Fusion means that many operations incur no extra cost over that of the traversal; for example, `map (*2) (xs ++ ys)` costs less than the sum of the costs of `map (*2)` and `++`, because GHC eliminates the intermediate list produced.

Answer (score 14):

Haskell lists are singly linked, so `cons`, `head` and `tail` are O(1) while `init` and `last` are O(*n*).

If you need better performance, consider using the `Seq` type from [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html), which provides O(1) access to both ends of the list. Internally it uses [2-3 finger trees](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html).